# Game Center entitlement

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I just submitted my game (which interacts with Game Center) for review on iOS app store but haven't enabled Game Center entitlement. Is it really necessary to enable it, remove the previous build from review and submit it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**
Your app is most likely to be rejected, and you will have a message in the Resolution Center asking you to enable the Game Center entitlement. So don't lose more time and do it now.